# When is one ideal the cube of another?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$ be an imaginary quadratic fields. Let $ \alpha = a+b\sqrt{-m}$ with $ N(a+b\sqrt{-m})=\beta^3$ (i.e norm of $ \alpha$ is a cube).
Then what is the condition to show that ideal $\langle\alpha\rangle$ is a cube of an ideal in $ K.$

Any help in direction is helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\alpha|\beta$, what does that tell you about their norms?

Answer (score 1):

I would factor the ideal $(a+b\sqrt{-m}\,)$. It certainly is not enough for the norm to be a cube integer, as you see from the example $5(2+i)$, with $m=1$. The norm is $125$, but the original is not a cube. What you want to look for is that every prime shows up to a power divisible by $3$, but of course that is just a restatement of your original question.

Comment: Mr.Lubin thank you for your response. I would like to know if $ N(\alpha)$ is a cube then is element $\alpha $ it self(not ideal) a cube. What are the conditions.

Comment: Sorry to be thick. Your question deals with principal ideals $I=(\alpha)$ for which the norm of $I$ is a cube integer. And you ask for conditions under which $I$ might be a cube ideal. I can’t think of any outside my answer above, which shows a simple example of a principle ideal with cube norm that isn’t a cube ideal. Fine distinctions I leave to you.

Comment: Now, once more: rereading your original question and your comment, I see that you’re asking two somewhat different questions.